# Trying to use Spring LDAP for coding

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-ldap, apacheds

I am trying to use Spring LDAP for coding

```xml
<ldap-server ldif="classpath:my-ldap-clone.ldif" />
```

but I get this error

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/directory/server/core/DirectoryService
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download ApcheDS from below link
http://directory.apache.org/ or get complete jar from [here](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/apache/directory/server/apacheds-all/1.5.7/apacheds-all-1.5.7.jar) 
I have used to work with Spring Security 3.0.5 with LDAP (Spring LDAP 1.3). That time i didn't met requirement of ApacheDS. Check your version of Spring Secuirty which may have dependency with ApacheDS.

Answer (score 13):

Using maven :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I doubt it is a good idea to add that big dependency (10MB!) if you need only a fraction of it. For instance, spring-security-ldap requires only 5 jars, see here : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-ldap/3.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: I have the same error. I'm new to Maven, but shouldn't dependencies be downloaded by Maven automatically? Why does this need to be specified explicitly in my app's pom.xml? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Maven, these actually come from an optional dependency of `spring-security-ldap`.

Using `apacheds-all` is a bad idea because it embeds a lot of rather common dependencies, like slf4j and dom4j. You would easily get into classloader issues with it.

Instead, you should look inside the pom of the `spring-security-ldap` version your are using, for the `apacheds` optional dependencies, and copy them over to your pom without the `<scope>` and `<optional>` elements (unfortunately there is no better way to handle optional dependencies with Maven).

For instance, with [`spring-security-ldap` 4.2.2](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/security/spring-security-ldap/4.2.2.RELEASE/spring-security-ldap-4.2.2.RELEASE.pom), it would give:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>apacheds-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>apacheds-core-entry</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-shared</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
    <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

(it looks like it hasn't changed since at least 3.2)